# nested for loop and i cannot get what i want

Tags: java

```
public class practice extends ConsoleProgram {

    public static int max(int num1, int num2) {
        int result;

        if (num1 > num2)
            result = num1;
        else 
            result = num2;  

        return result;     
    }  

    public void run () {     
        for (int i = 0; i<=10; i+=2){
            for (int j = 1; j < 10; j*=2) {   
                println( max(i,j));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this code? When I run it I do not get any max (i,j) but only a single number in a row.

Comment: It does what you told it to do. Prints the masimum value from the actual values of i and j variables... For each iteration of i and j, that is...

Comment: println( max(i,j)); should print one max number. what do you expect?

Comment: Maximum of 2 numbers will be either 1 of the 2 numbers only. What else are you expecting there?

Comment: "When I run it I do not get any max (i,j) but only a single number in a row." -  What exactly do you want to accomplish?.. It is doing what you have asked from it...

Comment: Can you give an example of the 'single number in a row'

Comment: Except that your max method is unnecessarily verbose, I don't see anything wrong per se.

Comment: `but only a single number in a row` this is because of `println()` which prints a single row and `max()` which returns a single value.

Comment: It prints, `1
2
4
8
2
2
4
8
4
4
4
8
6
6
6
8
8
8
8
8
10
10
10
10`, What did you expect?

Comment: [Greater than Symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_than_symbol "It's works the way it should")

Comment: Please, keep yourself to the naming conventions! Class names start with a capital.

Comment: I was actually expecting to see max (i, j) and i realized that I did wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments in the  code:

```
public class practice extends ConsoleProgram {

    public static int max(int num1, int num2) {
        int result;

        if (num1 > num2) 
            result = num1;
        else 
            result = num2;  

        return result;     
    }  

    public void run () {     
        for (int i = 0; i<=10; i+=2){
            for (int j = 1; j < 10; j*=2) {   
                System.out.println( max(i,j)); // instead of println() unless static import
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Test it:** http://ideone.com/YNXsKA

Comment: No, the original code returned num2 when num1==numb2, which was fine.

Comment: @MichaëlBenjaminSaerens Hey, missed that one in fuzz. Corrected now. :D

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write your own `max()`. Rewriting library methods tested by zyllion of programmers is not a good practice, you can easily make a mistake in your own implementation. This [works](http://ideone.com/5cb4xZ):

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i += 2)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < 10; j *= 2)
            {
                System.out.println(Math.max(i,j));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the same as a normal java program

```
package com;

public class TestRun {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i<=10; i+=2){
            for (int j = 1; j < 10; j*=2) {   
                System.out.println( max(i,j));
            }
        }

    }
     public static int max(int num1, int num2) {
            int result;
            if (num1 > num2)
                result = num1;
            else 
                result = num2;  
            return result;     
        }  
}
```

The output i got was

> 1 2 4 8 2 2 4 8 4 4 4 8 6 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 10 10 10 10

Is that what you are expecting ??

Answer (score 0):

"I was actually expecting to see max (i, j) and i realized that I did wrong.."

If you want to write string, you have to use it in quotes like :

```
System.out.println("max(i,j)");
```